# Run Grunt deploy task -> Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found

Tags: magento2, deploy, grunt

I NodeJs installed, I installed the Magento2 Grunt that works, but if I run the command "grunt deploy" it delete all from the folder pub/static/ but do not deploy and returns me the error below. Can someone help me?

---

Running "deploy" task

Cleaning "pub/static"...>> "pub/static" is empty.

Deploying Magento application...

**Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/Projects/Magento2Theme/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php on line 64**

Done, without errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You php do not have `intl` extension. You can verify it by run `php -i`.

In many cases this problem appear when you have different php version/configurations for apache and cli. For example if use install MAMP on MacOsX that you will have different version. To use php in this case you need specify full path to php like `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php`

To change it you need to do  folowing steps:

Edit  `~/.bash_profile` and add

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.x.x/bin:$PATH
```

where `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.x.x` should be patch to your latest wersion

In Terminal, run `source ~/.bash_profile`

In Terminal, type in `which php` and look for the updated patch. If everything was successful, It should output the new path to MAMP PHP install.

In case it doesn't output the correct path, try closing the terminal window (exit fully) and open again, it should apply the changes (Restart in short).

Comment: My Php version is 7.0.0
-------
php -v
PHP 7.0.0 (cli) (built: Dec  8 2015 16:39:19) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
------
sh-3.2# which php
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0//bin/php
-------
I know all these issues right version of PHP that were already done, and done correctly permissions (chmod and chown) and although these do not work.

Comment: Do you see intl extension in "php -i" output?

Comment: php -i
 -------- '--enable-intl'

intl

Internationalization support => enabled
version => 1.1.0
ICU version => 52.1
ICU Data version => 52.1

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
intl.default_locale => no value => no value
intl.error_level => 0 => 0
intl.use_exceptions => 0 => 0

Comment: Installing php intl extension worked for me